# Auto populate timestamp in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I come from Relational Database background and we have a way to populate timestamp for row creation and update. 
I am having difficulty finding similar feature for DynamoDB.

I checked DynamoDB to check if they support autopopulate the date timestamp for every entry in dynamoDB. I see it is possible to create random ID but that is not what I need.

My usecase is to add a timestamp entry automatically when I add any entry to DynamoDB Table. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Java Solution using Annotation (Data modelling package)**

You can use the **`DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp`** annotation.

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
public Date getCreatedDate() { return createdDate; }
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) { this.createdDate = createdDate; }

@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
public Date getLastUpdatedDate() { return lastUpdatedDate; }
public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) { this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate; }
```

[DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.html)

Comment: Currently, this wouldn't work with Java 8 Date types.

Comment: Just to note here, these timestamps are set up on Java side, not DynamoDB side.

Comment: This helps, but this only works when the mapper is also generating the key.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such functionality like 
`DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP` or `UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
You will have to set the date by yourself.

However if you want to keep track of changes on updates then you can use something like [atomic counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

Thus on every update your will increment the counter value.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me, using **aws-sdk-version 2.17.169**:

First, you need to define the extension to support

AutoGeneratedTimestampRecordExtension.

```
    @Bean
    public DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient(){
        return DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient())
                .extensions(AutoGeneratedTimestampRecordExtension.create())
                .build();
    }
```

Then, create a converter for **java.time.Instant**. As this is the only one supported at the time.

```
import java.time.Instant;
public class InstantToStringTypeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Instant> {

    @Override
    public String convert(Instant instant) {
        return instant.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant unconvert(String s) {
        return Instant.parse(s);
    }
```

Finally, on your model, add the annotations:

```
    @DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InstantToStringTypeConverter.class)
    public Instant getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Instant created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InstantToStringTypeConverter.class)
    public Instant getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Instant updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }
```

See some reference [here](https://github.com/gakinson/dyanamodb-enhanced-DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestamp-annotation)