# Update timestamp in dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want CREATE_DATE and LAST_UPDATED fields in DynamoDB table. It is creating those fields with initial values for both fields as current date. But when some of the columns get updated it does not update the LAST_UPDATED column with new date.

I am using DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp annotation and both CREATE_DATE and LAST_UPDATED are of type java.util.date

@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    private Date CREATE_DATE;

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
private Date LAST_UPDATED;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.html.

Can anyone tell what else needs to be added if I am missing anything ?
Or I need to handle update date in code and it would not be auto populated?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto populate timestamp in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098797/auto-populate-timestamp-in-dynamodb)

Comment: I used DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy looking at same stackoverflow answer. The code does not show getter and setter because I am using lombok getter and setter.

Comment: Does the attr name matches on the table? also check field types