# Auto Populate Time in Epoch format in DynamoDB

Tags: java, database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, epoch

Im pretty new to DynamoDB. Im trying to auto populate createdTimeStamp in epoch Time when I persist my record using JAVA application.
    So far I couldn't find a solution.
    I was only able to find how to auto-populate the TimeStamp as String : [Auto populate timestamp in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098797/auto-populate-timestamp-in-dynamodb)

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
public Date getCreatedDate() { return createdDate; }
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) { this.createdDate = createdDate; }

@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
public Date getLastUpdatedDate() { return lastUpdatedDate; }
public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) { this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate; }
```

Please help how to do something like above to save time as a number (i.e epoch time in milliseconds. ex: 1516169930709)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.java), it looks like you should just be able to use a `Long` property:

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
public Long getLastUpdatedDate() { ... }
public void setLastUpdatedDate(Long value) { ... }
```

Note that it has to be `Long` rather than `long` as per the comment:

> Primitives such as `long` are not supported since the unset (or null) state can't be detected.

Comment: Any workaround for the same with AWS Java Sdk v2.
I need to use `@DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute` but this only supports Instant. Can we make this work with Long?

Comment: @abstractKarshit: I have no idea, I'm afraid. I haven't used the AWS SDK myself - I was just looking at the documentation.