# SDK autogenerated timestamp attribute for DynamoDB using C#/.NET

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-net

My question is similar to [Auto populate timestamp in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098797/auto-populate-timestamp-in-dynamodb), but I'm using C#/.NET. I could not find an equivalent `DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute` using the object persistence model. How do I go about auto managing `CreatedDate` and `LastUpdatedDate` properties?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no `DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute` in the DynamoDB .NET object persistence model.

You will have to implement this yourself.

I could think of the easiest way being to just generate the timestamps when you create/update the object.